# How do I make a button move as the label next to it changes width?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I feel like this is something I can do with grids (or maybe a horizontal stack panel), but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this. This is on a Silverlight page, though I assume a solution for WPF will work just as well. At the top I have a label, centered on the page, which shows a current page's title. To the left of this label is a button. Since the label's text can be anything, it, while still centered, can be 400 pixels to 50 pixels wide. Is there a simple way to make the button always be 20 pixels to the left of the label's left hand edge?

Comment: Could you just call a function every time you resize the label to position the button correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following XAML does it:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Button"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Some Text in a Label"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

The Grid will reposition the Button whenever the width of the Label changes. No need for a frequently called update method.

Comment: You've made several edits since putting this up, I'll give you a few minutes to make sure you're sure :)

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to call a function to position your button. Call this method after every place you re-size the label.

```
public void RepositionButton(int horizontalSpacing)
{
    int newXPos = lblLabel.Position.X - btnButton.Width - horizontalSpacing;
    int newYPos = lblLabel.Position.Y;

    btnButton.Position = new Point(newXPos, newYPos);
}
```

You might want to modify the math of the Y position if it needs to be centered vertically.